# Customize will_paginate button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Is there any way to customize will_paginate control button to add more button like FIRST and LAST, not only previous and next buttons. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first page is pretty easy:

```
link_to 'First Page', :action => :whatever, :page => 1
```

The last page a little tricky, in your model class add:

```
class << self
  # number of records per page, from the will_paginate docs
  def per_page
    20
  end

  # takes a hash of finder conditions and returns a page number
  # returns 1 if nothing was found, as not to break pagination by passing page=0
  def last_page_number(conditions=nil)
    total = count :all, :conditions => conditions
    [((total - 1) / per_page) + 1, 1].max
  end
end
```

now you can do:

```
link_to 'Last page', :action => :whatever, :page => Model.last_page_number
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are paginating @users then put these links in your view

```
<%= link_to 'First Page', :action => 'index', :page => 1 %>
<%= will_paginate @users %>
<%= link_to 'Last Page', :action => 'index', :page => @users.page_count %>
```

Comment: that would be a good solution if page_count was a method that returned the number of pages. unfortunately will_paginate doesn't have that method built in

Comment: sorry but i am using this method in rails 2.8 and its working for me fine.